# Can't explain leading whitespace in FlowDocument

Tags: wpf, xaml, whitespace, flowdocument

I'm using a conventional FlowDocument setup with a `Floater` and a `Run` to wrap text around an image. I get a leading whitespace that I don't understand. Can anybody help? (Before anybody suggests removing the `Run`: I want to use an actual Run element here because I have situations where the text comes in via databinding).

```
<FlowDocumentScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">                
    <FlowDocument PagePadding="5" TextAlignment="Left">
        <Paragraph FontFamily="Segoe UI" FontSize="12">
            <Floater Width="32" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,0,2,2" Padding="0">
                <BlockUIContainer>
                    <Image Width="28" Height="28" Source="../imgscr/BassClef_32x.png" />                           
                </BlockUIContainer>
            </Floater>
            <Run Text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin et ante erat. Duis ut scelerisque nisl. Maecenas rutrum sapien vel dolor imperdiet egestas. Duis vel purus at leo hendrerit venenatis. Aenean nibh dui, ornare eu consequat nec, dapibus vel mauris. In bibendum urna efficitur ipsum auctor consequat. Phasellus nunc neque, mollis eget felis eu, placerat pharetra velit. Sed auctor posuere turpis vitae lobortis. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit." />
        </Paragraph>
    </FlowDocument>
</FlowDocumentScrollViewer>
```

The leading whitespace (notice it before the L in Lorem) is visible at runtime and in the visual XAML editor, so this looks like intended behavior. Can somebody explain why and how I fix this? I checked the whole visual tree via Snoop and can't find the cause.

[image: Leading Whitespace - Why?]

Comment: Could it be coming from the [`TextIndent`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.paragraph.textindent) property of `Paragraph` somehow, a style maybe?

Comment: Doing this doesn't fix it: `<Paragraph FontFamily="Segoe UI" FontSize="12" TextIndent="0">` (Setting it to non-zero also does ident as expected). If so, it's default behavior - I don't have any reference to TextIndent anywhere in the codebase. And I'm not styling my assorted FlowDocument elements anywhere.

Comment: I'm seeing the same behavior if I create a brand new project and paste your XAML in to a new window.

Comment: Setting `TextIndent` to `-3` visually fixes it for me, but that is hardly a good solution.

Comment: Also, removing the `Floater` makes the indent go away.  I wonder if there is some sort of conflict.

Comment: @BradleyUffner Well, at least that's *a* solution :)

Comment: I can't guarantee that it will work at all text, DPI scales, and font sizes though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove a whitespace between end of Floater and Run, like this:

```
</Floater><Run Background="Red" 
                Text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit
```

[image]

Comment: Fixes it for me.  Though my XAML formatter doesn't like it and keeps trying to move the `Run` to the next line.  I really don't like how the formatting of the XAML is affecting the output this way. Element positioning in the source shouldn't affect layout.

Comment: Yes, Ctrl+K,D in XAML editor in Visual studio also does this. Some tools try to be too smart.

Comment: This is indeed the answer. And this actually does strike me as a bug in VS (using VS2015): there were no actual (white)space characters after the `</Floater>` statement in my XAML. And the leading space characters before the `<Run>` on the next line don't cause the single space char, either (regardless of whether I use space or tabs to indent that line). It seems to be the linebreak character between both XAML elements, which is interpreted as a leading space. Only solution is to have both statements in the same line.